# Facebook login on web laravel and android mobile application

Tags: java, android, facebook, api, laravel

I am trying to develop two applications web and mobile. Web and API is done with laravel 5. Both use email / password authorization and facebook login. Mobile application will use mentioned API. (I understand that I could use the API with AngularJS for web application but this is bit too advanced at the moment)

I  managed to marry facebook with larvel, so I can create and login to the app with credentials or login using facebook. Users are stored in user table and if user logins with FB its access token is stored in the same table. Android mobile application uses facebook login via facebook SDK. I am using the same facebook app ID for both with the same permission scope.  My problem is that access tokens generated by both processes are different so user using facebook via web application has different token than user using facebook via mobile.

So if I follow the logic, identifying facebook user to access back-end data by email and access token does not work, as email field in table is unique and by overriding access token from either web or mobile application makes no sense. So scenario is i have two different users even they come from the same facebook account.

I suspect my logic is incorrect and would like ask you for help / explanation what is the proper way of authorizing the same facebook user on web and mobile app concurrently.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of access tokens you should use fbid to identify a user. It is part of the response returned from facebook api.

For PHP:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/php/howto/profilewithgraphapi/4.0.0

For Android:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/graph

Comment: Thanks for prompt reply. I would not say I have problem identifying the user but using access token with graph api. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens provides tokens are portable so this is the reason I store it in the database so i could read them and use for querying graph from mobile or web.

Comment: @dascorp Hmm. I get your point, that you can store access tokens as well to access graph api in the future. But using access tokens as a sole identifier, when logging in on different devices is not the solution (different access token are bound to be generated).  You might encounter the same problem as explained in above problem statement.

Answer (score 0):

Step 1 – Visit the following url https://developers.facebook.com/apps/ and create a new facebook app.

Step 2 – Create facebook app with email and app name
Step 3 – Then, Navigate to setting->advanced and add redirect URL
Step 4 – Now, add valid auth redirect url. So, click facebook login->setting and add valid auth redirect URL
Step 5 – Finally, Navigate to facebook developers dashboard and copy the following App ID and App SECRET

composer require laravel/socialite

Create Model
Step 6 – Install Jetstream Auth
Step 7 – Build Routes
Create Controller
go threw this URL https://www.tutsmake.com/laravel-8-facebook-login-tutorial-step-by-step/